# spread state in react redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-reducers

I want to know what does `...state` inside `{ ...state }` do? Is it to change the value of the store to the initial value or to let the store be the latest value?

```
import * as actionType from "../actions/actionTypes";

const initialStore = {
  roomsCount: 0,
  resPerPage: 0,
  rooms: [],
  filteredRooms: 0,
  error: null,
  success: false,
};

const reducer = (state = initialStore, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case actionType.ALL_ROOM_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        success: true,
        rooms: action.rooms,
        roomsCount: action.roomsCount,
        resPerPage: action.resPerPage,
        filteredRooms: action.filteredRooms,
      };
    case actionType.ALL_ROOM_FAILED:
      return {
        ...state,
        error: action.err,
      };
  }
};
```

If at first I use this reducer, it'll be successful so `success` will be `true` and `error` will be `null`. But if it fails the 2nd time and I use `...state` in this situation, what is the success value? Is it the initial value (`false`) or does it keep the value from the first request (`true`)?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#spread_in_object_literals

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is called the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) and it basically allows you to "clone" the fields of one object into a new object.

In your example, `{ ...state, error: action.err }` means "copy all fields from `state`, but set the field `error` to `action.err`". It's very handy for this kind of logic where you want to change a very few fields but otherwise want to keep the original data.